# Fade in div with text

Tags: javascript, html, fadein

**(Can't use jquery)**

I want to make text appear, then disappear and show some other text. I want the text to slowly fade in. 
How can I do this with pure javascript?

***Thanks!***

Comment: I assume that there are more constraints than just "can't use jquery". Do those constraints stop you from using RGBA for color values?

Comment: See https://codepen.io/ssddayz/pen/zKkaBQ

Comment: I can use RGBA, yes. @AndrewMorton

Comment: Thank you, @NoChance, I think that will work for fading out! But I also need it to fade in first.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a *"how to"* tutorial service or a free code writing service. Solution to your question should be an easy web search to get started with. Then when you have problems with actual code ask questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go.

```js
const textDiv = document.createElement("div")
document.body.appendChild(textDiv);
textDiv.style.transition = "opacity 1s ease";
textDiv.innerHTML = "Initial Text";
setTimeout(()=>{
  textDiv.style.opacity = 0
},1000);
setTimeout(()=>{
  textDiv.style.opacity = 1
  textDiv.innerHTML = "Some other text";
},2000);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can select that html tag which you want to fade in or fade out and use javascript fadeIn() and fadeOut functions with miliseconds you want.also you can add or edit text using innerText() function

Comment: fadeIn and fadeOut are jQuery functions, which are precluded for an answer to this particular question.

Comment: Watch this it can be useful w.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_display.asp